# How to query last modified column of snowflake stage metadata

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have an aws s3 bucket where same file is getting rewritten every day.
And we need to load that file in snowflake which is only loaded today.

Copy command is just working fine. however when a new file is not loaded it just load the previous one which is not needed. instead it should throw an error for the team to know.

We can query the last_modified date:

```
ls @stage_name
```

or we can get the stage metadata information.

By query

```
select metadata@filename from @stage_name
```

But I am not able to find any way of querying or filtering `last_modified` column of stage.

Comment: Can't you remove the stage file after it is loaded to snowflake?

Comment: What is the `COPY INTO` command you are using?  I don't think your issue is with the last_modified date, but rather how you are handling errors in the `COPY` command.

Comment: loading same file isn't a duplicate loading, something snowflake should throw error while copy command ?

Comment: @RajibDeb thats the challenge, we dont have permission to remove or move file in S3

Comment: @PIG copying the same file does not throw error. it just dont loads file unless we use force=true; if we get error message instead it will solve the issue, as the team will get notified.

Answer (score 5):

The ls command is a metadata query. While you can't filter on that, you can filter on the result set that it generates:

```
ls @MYSTAGE;
-- You must run this immediately after the previous query in the same session
select * from table(result_scan(last_query_id()));
```

There are two complications though. First, the name of the metadata columns is lowercase, so be sure to use lower case names in your filters and wrap them in double quotes. The second problem is the date field is not in a format that lends itself well to filtering in a query. To address this problem, I wrote a UDF to convert last_modified fields to a timestamp for easier filtering:

```
-- Convert the last modified value from the Snowflake LIST
-- command into a timestamp.
create or replace function LAST_MODIFIED_TO_TIMESTAMP(LAST_MODIFIED string) 
returns timestamp_tz
as
$$
    to_timestamp_tz(left(LAST_MODIFIED, len(LAST_MODIFIED) - 4) || ' ' || '00:00', 'DY, DD MON YYYY HH:MI:SS TZH:TZM')
$$;
```

Then you can filter the results like this:

```
ls @TESTSTAGE;

select * from table(result_scan(last_query_id())) 
where LAST_MODIFIED_TO_TIMESTAMP("last_modified") < '2020-11-01' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The metadata FILE_LAST_MODIFIED can be used to get the modified date of the s3 bucket. It kind be used in a similar way to METADATA$FILENAME.

```
`SELECT METADATA$FILENAME, METADATA$FILE_LAST_MODIFIED FROM @stage_name;`
```

will give you the bucket's name and also the last_modified date of the bucket.